# How do I create an ignore list of several items in SVN?

Tags: svn, svnignore, svn-propset

I'm creating an ignore list on a Windows machine using the following command line:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "bin" Fardis.Test
```

The directory tree structure is:

```
\src\
\src\Fardis.Test\
\src\Fardis.Test\bin\
\src\Fardis.Test\obj\
```

I'm running that command while my current directory is `\src`. This works fine, but I want to add another folder, `\src\Fardis.Test\obj\` to the ignore list, but it fails. I tried the following:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "bin obj" Fardis.Test
svn propset svn:ignore "bin, obj" Fardis.Test
svn propset svn:ignore "bin; obj" Fardis.Test
```

After issuing which one of them, `svn status` shows that none of folders bin or obj are added to the ignore list.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `svn propedit` instead of `svn propset`, and put each pattern on a separate line in the editor window.

Also take a look at [setting `global-ignores` in your config](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config) for files and directories that should be ignored in *any* working copy.  That's usually a better way to exclude debug and binary output from directories containing lots of projects.

Answer (score 26):

I usually create a .svnignore file. See [svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3)
Then do:

```
$ svn propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore .
  property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'
```

.svnignore:

```
*.pyc
*~
```

**EDIT:** I add the .svnignore to the repo also to keep track of it.

Comment: your solution seems greatly too. tnks.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work recursively like with Git. You'd probably need to add the `-R` parameter to apply the file contents to all currently existing (not future!) subdirectories, but the patterns are probably wrong for the subdirectories.

Comment: Or use `svn:global-ignores` if your are at subversion 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

## Method

There is flexible way without using `global-ignores`.

For example, you can create two files: `.svn-ignore` and `.svn-ignore-recur`.

.svn-ignore-recur

```
.idea
*.pyc
*.aux
*.out
*.ilg
*.toc
64bit-Debug
```

.svn-ignore

```
.idea
*.pyc
*.aux
*.out
*.ilg
*.toc
64bit-Debug
# below is difference
base
ta.txt
ta.html
```

Then you ought to call two commands (sequence is important).

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F .svn-ignore-recur . --recursive
svn propset svn:ignore -F .svn-ignore .
```

So, you get the way to ignore some files recursively, and some other files in the root of your repository.

To simplify a problem it is reasonably to create `.sh` or/and `.bat` files:

**!svn-ignor.bat**

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F .svn-ignore-recur . --recursive
svn propset svn:ignore -F .svn-ignore .
```

**!svn-ignor.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

sh ./!svn-ignor.bat
```

Of course you ought to add file:

```
svn add .svn-ignore* !svn-ignor.*
```

## Additional

It is clear you cat create file like `.svn-ignore-some-subdir`

```
*.dvi
*.cot
seven_doo
```

and call

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F .svn-ignore-some-subdir ./sub/sub1/sub2
```